# Upgraded TFS2012.4 to TFS2013.4, and now work item data has changed

Tags: tfs, upgrade

After upgrading from TFS2012.4 to TFS2013.4, the data associated with some of our work items has completely changed.

There were no errors encountered during upgrade.  All project collections upgraded successfully.

Now, some work item bugs became test suites and the created by, created date, work item title all changed.

Any idea how or why this would happen?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, here is what we found out:

1. Test Plans/Test Suites are being converted into work items as part of the updates to TFS2013.3.  This resulted in all of our former test plan items being converted into work items automatically.
2. No work item data was lost. This was all expected behavior.
3. Users were pulling reports on work items during a warehouse/analysis cube rebuild and got back incorrect data which made it appear that work items were lost or overwritten.